# java class using jaxb api failing in jira with : Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found

Tags: java, command-line, jaxb, launch

I am writing a plugin for Jira which involves parsing of XML documents. I am using JAXB to do so (XML to pojos and vice versa)
So have a class which generates XML from pojos using JAXB. it looks like...

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

Class Parser {
  public void m1() {
    ...
    // code which uses classes in javax.xml.bind.*
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
   Parser p=new Parser();
   p.m1();

  } 
}
```

The mentioned packages will come with JDK distribution (rt.jar). so i haven't relayed on anything else to run the class.

when i launch it from command line using 'java' it's working properly. but, when i package
it as a jar and put it as plugin in Jira it's failing with the following error

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:152)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:299)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
```

This is on the same machine. only difference i could see is unlike launching from command line, when i deployed it in Jira, it's not calling the main() but m1() by instantiating.

I am wondering what is happening ! it's on the same machine. i do not know how Jira launches the application (as i am launching from command line).

Comment: What JDK version are you building on? What JDK is JIRA running on? What version of JIRA?

Comment: JDK version is '1.6.0_15' & Jira version is '4.0.1' Jira is running on the same machine so should use the same JDK

Comment: hey, i came acroos this http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html

okay, but still i am wondering why it's getting failed

Comment: trying to understand this http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/02/howitworks_runn.html

something related ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `com.sun.xml.bind` package is part of the JAXB RI (http://jaxb.dev.java.net/), so you probably have that on your classpath somewhere.

Java6 has it's own version of JAXB included, in the `com.sun.xml.internal.bind` package, so you don't usually need the RI in Java6 .

The RI *can* made made to work with Java6 , but it's uphill battle, and usually ends up with this sort of problem.

Comment: nope. i have cleared my CLASSPATH. so far i understand, what's happening is, as i am using 'javax.xml.bind.*' located in rt.jar (probably these classes internally use com.sun.xml.internal.bind.* ).   when i run my program thru CL, 'bootstrap Class loader' is loading the required classes so program goes smooth.  when i deploy it in Jira(tomcat) some other 'ClassLoader' is trying to load the classes and causing the problem

Comment: hope i was clear.

here is the link
http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/10936_2248831_2/Java-Class-Loading-The-Basics.htm

I really need some help i can't figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is sort of a late answer, but for people landing here there are a few things not mentioned in the other posts that is of importance when developing plug-ins for JIRA (and other Atlassian products).

First JIRA, or rather Atlassian, has two types of plug-ins, see [Differences between Plugins1 and Plugins2](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Differences+between+Plugins1+and+Plugins2)

Since it was a ClassNotFoundException (and JIRA v4.0.1), I assume the plug-in is a Plugin2, which can be used in JIRA v4 and later.

From JIRA v4, JIRA acts as an OSGi container, and hence Plugin2 is an OSGi bundle. In OSGi every bundle has its own set of class loaders. This enables different bundles to have different versions of the same jars, and to be hot deployed, among other things. The catch, however, is that not all packages from the JDK is per default available to these class loaders. This is explained under [Plugins, bundles and OSGi](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Setting+OSGi+Manifest+Instructions+in+your+Plugin) on the [Atlassian Developers web page](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/HOME/Welcome). A more detailed description can be found in the blog [Exposing the boot classpath in OSGi](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/01/19/exposing-the-boot-classpath-in-osgi/) at Springsource. The second paragraph there even has the title **NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun…**

Such much for the theory.

When developing a plug-in for JIRA with the Atlassian SDK, Maven is used behind the scenes, see [Atlassian Plugin SDK Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Atlassian+Plugin+SDK+Documentation). So there will be a pom.xml in the plug-in project. To include JDK packages in the plug-in, one can add a **`<SystemProperties>`** tag to the **maven-jira-plugin** (for other Atlassian products, there's a corresponding maven plugin), and set the **bootdelegation** property (and you might want to set java to 1.6 for the **maven-compiler-plugin**):

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${jira.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>atlassian.org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation</name>
                        <value>sun.*,com.sun.*</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

The listed packages will then be available to the bundle. Be aware, though, boot delegation is not a fix it all solution, and should only be used with restriction. Read more at [Boot Delegation](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Boot_Delegation) and [Avoid Classloader Hacks](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Avoid_Classloader_Hacks).

Under the dependencies, one can set the **jaxb-api** version needed:

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-jira</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-rest-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

It's not always necessary to explicitly have a dependency on **jaxb-api**. For example the **atlassian-rest-common** plug-in above has a transitive dependency on **jaxb-api**.
Important is to understand the setting of **scope**. Look at [Setting OSGi Manifest Instructions in your Plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Setting+OSGi+Manifest+Instructions+in+your+Plugin#SettingOSGiManifestInstructionsinyourPlugin-UsingAtlassiancode) (same page as *Plugins, bundles and OSGi* but further down).

The intrigued can learn more at [OSGi Alliance Specifications](http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/HomePage) and [OSGi Community Wiki](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Answer (score 5):

Finally I was able find out the reason.

There are many `ClassLoaders` involved while loading the plugins in JIRA (Felix). which will not delegate to 'bootstrap' `ClassLoader`. And hence the problem.

To know which `ClassLoader` loaded the `JAXBContext` class, use `JAXBContext.class.getClassLoader()` which will print some Felix `ClassLoader`.

It loaded the class from `jaxb-api.jar` instead of relying on `rt.jar` but they implemented the classes slightly different.  `rt.jar` version uses 
`com.sun.xml.bind.internal.v2.ContextFactory` where `jaxb-api` version uses `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`.

I am able to solve the issue using overlaoded method of JAXB which will take another parameter as `ClassLoader`.

It took quite some time. But, I am surprised by the inner details & my ignorance

Comment: `jaxb-api.jar` is part of the JAXB RI, which was what I suggested earlier, as are the implementation package names.

Comment: ernesto, how/what did you overload to specify the different bootloader.   I'm trying to marshall and unmarshall using jython and getting the opposite error.  the com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory is found but the com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory cannot be found.   from jython the JAXBContext.getClassLoader() method returns  org.python.core.SyspathJavaLoader