# WARNING: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, glassfish-3

I have integrated within a JSF app a few webservices through `Jersey`.  Everything works fine, even the OAuth identification is working.  BUT! When starting my webserver, I ALWAYS get this error :

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.mysite.webService
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.mysite.webService.Accounts
INFO: No provider classes found.

INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 03:31 PM'
```

```
SEVERE: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.OAuthProviderInjectionProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.RuntimeException: No OAuthProvider implementation found in the list of providers.
    at com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.<init>(OAuthProviderInjectionProvider.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

*(edit2: above is now solved)*

and this warning:

```
...

WARNING: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found by com.sun.jersey.glassfish.v3.osgi.jersey-gf-server [157]]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:148)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:361)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:95)
```

Here is my `web.xml` relevant entries :

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.site.webService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My classes look as such :

```java
@Path("/rest")
public class MyClass {

    @GET 
    @Path("/{id}/results")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getResults(@Context HttpContext hc, @PathParam("id")) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I am using `Majorra 2.1.20` on `Glassfish 2.1.2.2` with `PrimeFaces 3.4.1` and `Jersey 1.17` as addons.  Developping in `Eclipse Juno` if this affects anything.

#### Edit

This does not prevent me from having everything in working order with regards to webservices.  But everytime I republish something on Glassfish, the error shows up.

As mentioned in an answer below, this should have been fixed in version 1.7 according to [JIRA bug JERSEY-709](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-709).  But I am very well on v. 1.17 and I'm still getting this.

I have also added a Warning I am getting within the stack trace.  If this can help determine the issue!

Searching the web : I have found [The same unresolved issue here](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Upgraded-Jersey-to-1-15-in-glassfish-3-1-2-2-Getting-org-jboss-weld-resources-spi-ResourceLoadingExcs-td7580264.html)

#### Edit 2

As answered below, updating my `OAuthClient.jar` did solve the first `error`.  I am STILL getting the `WARNING: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found`.

#### Edit 3 - Attempted Solution

Tried updating JAXB after what I thought would be a lead on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093963/java-class-using-jaxb-api-failing-in-jira-with-provider-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-co).  This did not lead to anything successful. Same warning.  When removing the Jersey bits in my `web.xml` this warning stops showing (just to confirm this is really initiating the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has gone away when upgrading to Jersey 1.18.

See https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1932

To upgrade Glassfish to Jersey 1.18 see : https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.18/glassfish.html

Answer (score 17):

In another context : standalone Java App, using Maven

In pom.xml, jaxb was defined using this lines :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Project compilation is successful, but when running, I received the same Exception 
(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory)

Issue was solved adding this lines before jaxb-api dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you this helped me, running Java10 with SpringBoot

Comment: Following EXACT same steps as this tutorial (https://youtu.be/NhY8q5B0s-s) will give me this error (Although it works for him), this will solve the issue as well :S. 
Thank you! Although this is very weird!

Comment: Also, it has to be this version, if I use last version of the library throws a
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.istack.Pool]
Error

Answer (score 0):

This should have been fixed in v1.7 as per [JERSEY-709](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-709).

Comment: This is what I thought as well and upgraded.  Just re-updated everything and am definetly running 1.17 `INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 03:31 PM'`.  Same error.

Comment: You mean you are definitely running 1.7? Because 1.17 != 1.7

Comment: I mean `1.17` as in : One dot Seventeen.

Comment: The bug is fixed in 1.7 and not 1.17. And unless I completely misunderstood the Jersey release numbering 1.7 is a much more recent release than 1.17. No?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was `one dot seven` vs `one dot seventeen`.  17 > 7.  Maybe I am missing something.  I'm sure I am running the most recent release of Jersey.

Comment: Duh! Of course. Sorry, you are correct. I was wrong about the version number scheme...

Comment: Versionning aside, as you mentioned, I was sure this was fixed in v. 1.7.  Which boggles my mind.

Comment: This is my bad.  My Jersey version was fine, but my version of the `oauth-client.jar` and `oauth-server.jar` and `oauth-signature.jar` were not updated as well as these are not packaged by default in Jersey (I assume).  Updating these solved the first error I had, still a `Warning` on server load (see update 2).

Answer (score 0):

M8, I met this as well on:

```
  NetBeans 7.2
  Glassfish 3.1.2.2 which have jersey 1.11, and jersey-oauth 1.11.
```

But it could work with:

```
  NetBeans 7.3
  Glassfish 3.1.2.2 which have jersey 1.11 (I didn't modify jars in glassfish/module folder)
  jersey 1.13 and jersey-oauth 1.13 (which is packed in war)
```

Then the exception no longer exist.

I'm still not quite sure how it is solved, but I hope this can help you.