# How to fix issue with JAXB and the Java POJO?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am trying to use JAXB in my maven application. However, when I go to launch the code it gives me an error saying `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException - with linked exception:`. I am not sure what it means but I believe it has to do something with the annotation. I took a look at some stack overflow questions related to this subject but they all show me someone of the same answer and it doesn't seem to work for me. My end goal is to read the contents of the `module` in my xml file. Thank you

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results
        xmlns="info"
        xmlns:coll="info"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="info">

    <IIsWebServiceImpl array="1"
        guid="063D0DD72D5F3A46B118D7A963306361" xsi:type="coll:com.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMWebService">
        <modules array="1" guid="FBVRKJNR75858NND2UJ3J2IC9C9R" xsi:type="coll:com.collation.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMModule">
            <fileName>D:\pubKSRF</fileName>
            <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
            <displayName/>
            <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
            <hierarchyType>KLMModule</hierarchyType>
        </modules>
        <modules array="2" guid="IJECI89585U5FJIDNVU3FI2NF" xsi:type="coll:com.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMModule">
            <fileName>d:\SRFdata</fileName>
            <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
            <displayName/>
            <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
            <hierarchyType>KLMModule</hierarchyType>
        </modules>
        <modules array="3" guid="VNJFVFV8238DNCNCJ3J4JNDIEJC875" xsi:type="coll:com.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMModule">
            <fileName>D:\srfData</fileName>
            <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
            <displayName/>
            <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
            <hierarchyType>KLMModule</hierarchyType>
        </modules>
        <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
        <displayName/>
        <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
        <hierarchyType>KLMWebService</hierarchyType>
    </IIsWebServiceImpl>
</results>
```

**Java:**

```
 try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ServiceSDK.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Modules customer = (Modules) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
            //StringReader customer = new StringReader(xml);

            //System.out.println(customer);
            System.out.println(customer);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Java Class:**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Modules {
    private String fileName;

    private String hierarchyType;

    private String isPlaceholder;

    private String array;

    private String displayName;

    private String guid;

    private String hierarchyDomain;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getFileName ()
    {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName (String fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getHierarchyType ()
    {
        return hierarchyType;
    }

    public void setHierarchyType (String hierarchyType)
    {
        this.hierarchyType = hierarchyType;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getIsPlaceholder ()
    {
        return isPlaceholder;
    }

    public void setIsPlaceholder (String isPlaceholder)
    {
        this.isPlaceholder = isPlaceholder;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getArray ()
    {
        return array;
    }

    public void setArray (String array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getDisplayName ()
    {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName (String displayName)
    {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getGuid ()
    {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid (String guid)
    {
        this.guid = guid;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getHierarchyDomain ()
    {
        return hierarchyDomain;
    }

    public void setHierarchyDomain (String hierarchyDomain)
    {
        this.hierarchyDomain = hierarchyDomain;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [fileName = "+fileName+", hierarchyType = "+hierarchyType+", isPlaceholder = "+isPlaceholder+", array = "+array+", displayName = "+displayName+", guid = "+guid+", hierarchyDomain = "+hierarchyDomain+"]";
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:241)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:477)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:599)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:594)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:239)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: So what is the exception? If you believe that text is empty, please user debugger, attach to the process and set "exception breakpoint" on JAXBException

Comment: @BorisTreukhov I will make an edit to the comment to show the error log

Comment: Refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416579/warning-provider-com-sun-xml-internal-bind-v2-contextfactory-not-found/16166407, you dont have appropriate provider jars in classpath