# class.getResource(".") returns null in Tomcat Server but works fine on standalone Java program

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I am trying to get the java.net.URL for SharePoint web service class in my application.
When I run the standalone java program to connect to SharePoint using java web service, works fine.
This is one of my Web Service generated Java class (which works fine from standalone):

```
static {
    try {
        URL baseUrl = com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.Lists.class.getResource(".");
        System.out.println("baseUrl::"+baseUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
 baseUrl::file:/C:/folder1/folder2/target/classes/com/microsoft/sharepoint/webservices/
```

For the same code when called from Tomcat server, the output is::

```
baseUrl::null
```

I tried googling and on relative path like:

```
MyTestClass.class.getResource("/com/microsoft/sharepoint/webservices");
```

standalone prg works fine, but on server the protocol is "bundle" where as the protocol is "file" for standalone, i am not sure whats the difference and how does it effect.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no reason why this should work at all. A resource isn't a file. It's much more likely to be in a JAR file than on the file system.

Comment: Did you try `com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.Lists.class.getClassloader().getResource(".")`?

Comment: Yes, tried with

    com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.Lists.class.getClassloader().getResource("‌​.")

no use, still it returns null when run on tomcat :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, the issue was with class loader and not picking the classes, this URL has more insight of the issue and fix:

[java class using jaxb api failing in jira with : Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093963/java-class-using-jaxb-api-failing-in-jira-with-provider-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-co)