# JDK 1.8 JAXB: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I am using JDK 1.8 in Eclipse to Unmarshaller xml to Java. This line throw up

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.dtd");


 javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Everything is loaded from jdk1.8. For example:

[Loaded javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\rt.jar]

Where is com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java class using jaxb api failing in jira with : Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093963/java-class-using-jaxb-api-failing-in-jira-with-provider-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hive-jdbc-1.1.0-standalone.jar in my classpath. Remove it solved the problem.

Comment: I had this problem with SquirrelSQL. Moving hive-jdbc-*.jar from my Java classpath solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Some stuff to try:

1. Check for typos in your classpath.
2. Try adding jaxb impl. (instead of jaxb-api)
3. Add a manifest file with module dependencies line:
   Dependencies: com.sun.xml.bind services
4. Read over this: http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-16722